# Responsive div relations

Tags: jquery, css

I have 2 div with some elements inside them.

I want to show a div when the width is >600px and hidden the other, and hidden a div when the width is >600px and show the other. I have tried with this code but it doesn't work:

```
@media (min-width: 601px) { 


 .organigramma-desktop {   
display: inline;
}

.organigramma-mobile {   
 display: none;
}}



@media (max-width: 600px) { 

 .organigramma-desktop {   
   display: none;
 }
  .organigramma-mobile {   
 display: inline;
 }
 }
```

thank you

Comment: What seems to go wrong? How did you code your HTML? Your media queries [seem to work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/cgk4xkrb/).

Comment: Your code as presented appears to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/yz7mxwa3/

Answer (score 0):

media queries are applied on top of existing styles so you should define the desktop styles and only add the mobile styles when needed

```
.organigramma-desktop {   
    display: inline;
}

.organigramma-mobile {   
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) { 
     .organigramma-desktop {   
       display: none;
     }

     .organigramma-mobile {   
        display: inline;
     }
 }
```

Comment: now it works perfect, there was also a problem with the div mobile inside the other, so it didn't work... thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Comment: Mark this as the answer so the question can be closed